# Creating dynamic JavaScript proxy for custom ApplicationService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I've read the ABP documentation.

Here is my solution architecture for my new project based on the ABP Framework.
First of all, I want to ask if there is anything wrong with this design?

[image]

I've registered all my app services to `IocManager` in my `Holitera.ApplicationModule`.
So now I can call my app services from MVC controllers. `RegionAppService` is my new AppService here.

Here is the registration:

[image]

And my `RegionAppService` class:

```
public class RegionAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Region, RegionDto,int>, IRegionAppService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Region> _regionRepository;
    public RegionAppService(IRepository<Region> regionRepository) :
        base(regionRepository)
    {
        CreatePermissionName = "CreateRegionPermission";
        _regionRepository = regionRepository;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a CRUD Razor page like the Roles view in the default template. But I couldn't register my custom `RegionAppService` to the JavaScript proxy services.

Do I need a dynamic Web API module to do that? Is that necessary? If it is, then how are Role, User, Customer, Account services registered to the dynamic JS proxy? I couldn't find the configuration for that. As much as I know there is no configuration for dynamic Web API module in the default MVC template? So I don't have an API module yet.

I'm going to need a dynamic JavaScript module later, but not now. First, I just want to handle this.

And by the way, what is the difference between dynamic AJAX call methods and dynamic Web API module? Are they same or if not, how?

Thanks :)

Comment: It works if `RegionAppService` is in the same assembly as `HoliteraApplicationModule`.

Comment: Thanx. I'll be fixing problem as u said.  But there must be an option for this configuration. Anyway thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> anything wrong with this design?

**Entity** and **DomainService** go in Core project. **Dto** and **AppService** go in Application project.
You can read about [NLayer Architecture](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/NLayer-Architecture).

It's how the other services are discovered, and the right approach.

> Do i need dynamic web api module to do that? Is that neccessary?

No.

> how are Role, User, Customer, Account services are registered to dynamic js proxy? I couldn't find the configuration for that. As much as i know there is no configuration for dynamic api module in default mvc template?

It's done in [YourProjectNameWebCoreModule](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/bb9d5aab6e5047d6d22d49831b473c0b3329b499/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Core/AbpProjectNameWebCoreModule.cs#L44-L47). You can create controllers for additional assemblies:

```cs
Configuration.Modules.AbpAspNetCore()
    .CreateControllersForAppServices(
        typeof(RegionAppService).GetAssembly()
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. I've got all my answers.